# Is there a way to simplify this function and how does this may look like?

Tags: python-3.x, nested-loops

I'm a total noob and I need some help here:

I will always **input** (into AttributeList) **a 2 dimensional nested list into this function**.

```
def CombineAttributes(AttributeList):



    NumAttributes = len(AttributeList)

        print("Got the following AttributeList: {}  , it has got {} Attributes in it and im going to Combine Everything now".format(AttributeList, NumAttributes) )



        if( NumAttributes > 10):
            print("MAXIMUM NUMBER OF 10 ATTRIBUTES REACHED")
        elif( NumAttributes == 1 ):
            List = [str(a) for a in AttributeList[0]]
        elif( NumAttributes == 2 ):
            List = [[str(a)+str(b) for a in AttributeList[0]] for b in AttributeList[1]]
        elif( NumAttributes == 3 ):
            List = [[str(a)+str(b)+str(c) for a in AttributeList[0]] for b in AttributeList[1] for c in AttributeList[2]]
        elif( NumAttributes == 4 ):
            List = [[str(a)+str(b)+str(c)+str(d) for a in AttributeList[0]] for b in AttributeList[1] for c in AttributeList[2] for d in AttributeList[3]]
        elif( NumAttributes == 5 ):
            List = [[str(a)+str(b)+str(c)+str(d)+str(e) for a in AttributeList[0]] for b in AttributeList[1] for c in AttributeList[2] for d in AttributeList[3] for e in AttributeList[4]]
        elif( NumAttributes == 6 ):
            List = [[str(a)+str(b)+str(c)+str(d)+str(e)+str(f) for a in AttributeList[0]] for b in AttributeList[1] for c in AttributeList[2] for d in AttributeList[3] for e in AttributeList[4] for f in AttributeList[5]]
        elif( NumAttributes == 7 ):
            List = [[str(a)+str(b)+str(c)+str(d)+str(e)+str(f)+str(g) for a in AttributeList[0]] for b in AttributeList[1] for c in AttributeList[2] for d in AttributeList[3] for e in AttributeList[4] for f in AttributeList[5] for g in AttributeList[6]]
        elif( NumAttributes == 8 ):
            List = [[str(a)+str(b)+str(c)+str(d)+str(e)+str(f)+str(g)+str(h) for a in AttributeList[0]] for b in AttributeList[1] for c in AttributeList[2] for d in AttributeList[3] for e in AttributeList[4] for f in AttributeList[5] for g in AttributeList[6] for h in AttributeList[7]]
        elif( NumAttributes == 9 ):
            List = [[str(a)+str(b)+str(c)+str(d)+str(e)+str(f)+str(g)+str(h)+str(i) for a in AttributeList[0]] for b in AttributeList[1] for c in AttributeList[2] for d in AttributeList[3] for e in AttributeList[4] for f in AttributeList[5] for g in AttributeList[6] for h in AttributeList[7] for i in AttributeList[8]]
        elif( NumAttributes == 10 ):
            List = [[str(a)+str(b)+str(c)+str(d)+str(e)+str(f)+str(g)+str(h)+str(i)+str(j) for a in AttributeList[0]] for b in AttributeList[1] for c in AttributeList[2] for d in AttributeList[3] for e in AttributeList[4] for f in AttributeList[5] for g in AttributeList[6] for h in AttributeList[7] for i in AttributeList[9] for j in AttributeList[10]]

        print("Im going to return the following after ive combined everything: {}".format(List))
        return List
```

example **input call**:

```
List = [['a','b','c','d'],[1,2,3,4]]
CombineAttributes(List)
```

**output** of this call:

```
Got the following AttributeList: [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['1', '2', '3', '4']]  , it has got 2 Attributes in it and im going to Combine Everything now
Im going to return the following after ive combined everything: [['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1'], ['a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2'], ['a3', 'b3', 'c3', 'd3'], ['a4', 'b4', 'c4', 'd4']]
```

I would be happy if i would be able to remove the maximum amount of Attributes (NumAttributes) and if i could remove the bunch of "if's" and "elif's" to shorten it into a couple of lines by looping through the list.

Please comment misunderstandings of my code or my question. Im curious about your answeres.

Comment: Is there a way to simplify this function? -- Of Course!

Comment: maybe have a look at itertools module it will certainly help here

Comment: That looks a lot like a work for `itertools.product`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use itertools product here to generate your merged data. note that the pair returned will be tuple in the list rather then lists.

```py
def CombineAttributes(data):
    print(f"Got the following AttributeList: {data} its got {len(data)} Attributes in it and im going to Combine Everything now")
    merged = [[]]
    for pair in product(*data[::-1]):
        if len(merged[-1]) == len(data[0]):
            merged.append([])
        merged[-1].append("".join(str(ele) for ele in pair[::-1]))
    merged.sort()
    print("Im going to return the following after ive combined everything:", merged)
    return merged

data = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
CombineAttributes(data)
data1 = [['a', 'b'], [1, 2], ['W', 'X']]
CombineAttributes(data1)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Got the following AttributeList: [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], [1, 2, 3, 4]] its got 2 Attributes in it and im going to Combine Everything now
Im going to return the following after ive combined everything: [['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1'], ['a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2'], ['a3', 'b3', 'c3', 'd3'], ['a4', 'b4', 'c4', 'd4']]
Got the following AttributeList: [['a', 'b'], [1, 2], ['W', 'X']] its got 3 Attributes in it and im going to Combine Everything now
Im going to return the following after ive combined everything: [['a1W', 'b1W'], ['a1X', 'b1X'], ['a2W', 'b2W'], ['a2X', 'b2X']]
```

Comment: this seem to solve my problem very well, im still testing it

Comment: The output is not in the right format, zip will happly fix the 2 attributes as it will give you columns instead of rows, but doesnt solve it for the 3 or more attribtues.

Comment: updated the answer. There may be an easier way to do this and you would need to test it against your other sets of attributes but this at least produces a sorted output you can either remove the sort of the order of the pairs are not important but it will at least pair them up correctly in the lists.

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative answer using `itertools.product` and comprehensions,  which gives you almost the exact output you asked:

```py
from pprint import pprint
from itertools import product

a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

b = ['1', '2', '3', '4']

axb = [
    [''.join(_) for _ in list(product(a, b))][_:_ + len(a)]
    for _ in range(0, len(a) * len(b), len(a))
]

pprint(axb)
```

Resulting in:

```py
[['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4'],
 ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4'],
 ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4'],
 ['d1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4']]
```

As you see, you will need to transpose `axb` to get the exact output needed. That can be achieved with `numpy.transpose()`, for example. Look:

```
>>> from numpy import transpose
>>> transpose(axb)
array([['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1'],
       ['a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2'],
       ['a3', 'b3', 'c3', 'd3'],
       ['a4', 'b4', 'c4', 'd4']], dtype='<U2')
>>>
```

If you want to stick with Python's standard modules, you can transpose the result with:

```py
axbcopy = axb.copy()
for i in range(len(axb)):
    for j in range(len(axb[0])):
        axbcopy[i][j] = axb[j][i]
```

Or, with a more Pythonic method:

```
axbt = list(map(list, zip(*axb)))
```

Where `axbt` will hold the final result.

Comment: the only thing with this is that it doesnt scale as a general solution like if he has 6 lists a, b, c, d, e, f for example

Comment: @ChrisDoyle, indeed. And one other thing that I just noticed is that he will need to transpose the matrix to get the exact desired output. In other words, something like `numpy.transpose(axb)`.

Comment: oh i didnt even realise that in my answer.....hmmm i need to have a rethink about my answer

Comment: yes that was exactly my problem in first place. Thanks for showing me some possibilities

Comment: are you able to show the output for a 2d list with 3 attribtues, as i can use zip to produce the output expected for the 2 attribute example but i need to know the expected output for 3 attributes